# Why Ubuntu 18.04 has LibreOffice 6.0.7? How can I upgrade that to version 6.28?

Tags: 18.04, software-installation, libreoffice

I recently saw a social media post from Libre Office about them phasing out Libre office 6.28 and moving to Libre office 6.3. But when I checked my fully updated 18.04, I see that I am having Libre office 6.0.7. Why my version of Libre Office is so old ? What can I do to get it updated to 6.28 and then automatically to 6.3 when Libre Office pushes it?

Comment: I think this addresses a different issue to that outlined in the suggested duplicates and is worthy of being retained - if not only because it brings the question up to date. The old thread was 7 years ago.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the LibreOffice PPA.

Open a terminal and enter:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa
```

Next run this command to update the list of packages available to install on your system:

```
sudo apt update
```

Finally, run this command to upgrade or install LibreOffice 6.0:

```
sudo apt install libreoffice
```

Once this command completes you can head to your application launcher of choice and launch LibreOffice.

To verity your upgrade went successfully just head to the Help > About option. You should see the correct version listed.

This is currently 6.3.2.2

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Graham . I was hoping to get 6.28 ( sort of their LTS ) not 6.3.2.2.

Comment: @user227495 For that you can use `ppa:libreoffice/libreoffice-6-2`. But that won't provide any major update such as 6.3, 6.4, etc.

Comment: @user227495 is there a specific reason to only go as far as 6.28? Version 6.3 has so many more features and fixes.

Comment: @Graham from what I read from Libre Office website, they recommend 6.28 if you don't need the latest version. 6.28 ( according to them ) have more bugs fixed and stable than 6.3 . Do correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @user227495 I'm using 6.3.2.2 almost every day and haven't noticed any problems. This bug reference was last updated today: https://bugs.freedesktop.org/buglist.cgi?order=bug_id&product=LibreOffice&query_format=specific

Comment: I see. It was never a personal choice. From the website, it looks like they promote 6.28 for office and people who do not want to use the bleeding-edge version (buggy).